# How to allow clang-format to format empty classes/structs on one line?

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

Having the following structs definitions:

```
struct city
{
};
struct country
{
};
```

I would like [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) to format it for me like

```
struct city {};
struct country {};
```

How can I achieve this?

I can see a lot of options like `AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine`, `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine` or `AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine` but no `AllowShortClassDefinitionsOnASingleLine` (or similar).

Comment: Can you post your clang-format config? It will hope us to understand what's happening.

Comment: I've been looking for this in vain too. AllowShortStructDefinitionsOnASingleLine would be nice. I use it for formatting short protocol frames.

Answer (score 6):

As of clang-format 12, the individual functionality that you required is, unfortunately, missing.

That is, if you want an empty struct / class to be in a single line, then you have to accept that the opening curly brace `{` always stays in the same line as `struct` or `class`. To do so, set

```yaml
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
```

Then you will have

```cpp
class A {};

class B {
  void foo() {}
};
```

If you want to achieve something like

```cpp
class A {};

class B 
{
  void foo() {}
};
```

Then I am afraid clang-format cannot do that as far as I know.

---

I will discuss some related options below.

First, assume we have set

```yaml
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

Without this, all the options that follow are ignored.

Then,

```yaml
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: false
```

would result in

```cpp
class Foo {
    // data members and member functions
};
```

In contrast,

```yaml
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true
```

would lead to

```cpp
class Foo 
{
    // data members and member functions
};
```

Now, given `AfterClass` is set to `true`, then `SplitEmptyRecord` determines whether an empty class will be split to two lines.

```yaml
BraceWrapping:
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
```

would result in

```cpp
class EmptyClass
{};
```

while

```yaml
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
```

would give you

```cpp
class EmptyClass
{
};
```

Sadly, none of these specifically address your problem.

For reference, see [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
```

Or you can try setting

```
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

and play around with `BraceWrapping`.
This option didn't work for me, though.

Comment: This isn't best solution because I still want class Sample { int a;}; with new lines ONLY empty class/struct :(